# How to make routing work in Nuxt3 when deployed to azure static web app

Tags: javascript, azure, vuejs3, nuxt3, azure-static-web-app

I have deployed my application to azure static web app and everything works great if I start form the route domain (ie, test.com) and navigate to test.com/shop from button links. However, if I start from test.com/shop as the initial page it will return a 500 error code. For other vuejs apps (quasar) I have published to azure I had to add a staticwebapp.config.json and include the following:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ],
  "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "index.html"
  },
}
```

However, for this nuxt3 (I am very new to it) I added this file hoping it would fix the issue but nope. So I am not sure do I need to do additional stuff to make this work? In my pages folder I have a shop page in there. So shouldnt it load that route by default or do I need to declare this route in the nuxt config or something? Typically I am use to using vue-router directly but nuxt has its own directories to go by. I would also note everything works as intended on my localhost when in development mode.

A link to the site can be seen here:
https://orange-mud-001cbf70f.3.azurestaticapps.net/

My navigation and the site in general is very incomplete so not everything works directs to somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error message related to 500 status code? And what exactly is your application structure - you have just the one file (and thus the only auto-generated route) `/pages/shop.vue`? How does the link on the button look like?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if trying to build locally?

Comment: I have added a link to the site so you can see the exact error.  As for building locally I just used yarn run build and no issues. also when I do yarn run dev I can go straight to the shop page via url and it finds it. Its just when its deployed to the static web app. I mean even if you navigate to any page once deployed and hit refresh. If its not the home page you are on it wont find it.

Comment: My application structure is really similar to a basic nuxt3 installlation. I have a pages folder, a components folder, and a layouts folder with two layouts I use (one for home page and one for shop page with different headers).